# Censor contact info like phone number or email address

Tags: php, regex, cakephp-1.3

I have a text-area in which a user can fill info about himself.

I  need to detect if user has filled phone no. or email address in that text-area.

I know that a fixed pattern can be matched with regex but how to handle various formats like:

```
9 7 8 5 8 7 

9, 7, 8, 5, 8, 7 

9.7.8.5.8.7 

Or any 6 or more consecutive number sepereated with \, -, etc
```

Please help.

Comment: You could first remove any non digit character from the string and then validate that ...

Comment: Please explain: What is "cencer" ;)

Comment: "cencer" is detect and remove.

Comment: @Daniel: Does this word exist in any language?

Comment: @djot: Sorry, i have edited the spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you'll be able to find all phone numbers and e-mail addresses in a string. It can get very complex. If you don't let people save their profile because you suspicious them to have invalid information, they may try so long until they find a pattern, that your regex won't handle. Someone may end up with:

```
My name is Peter at googleD0Tcom'on.
```

On the other hand you'll make people angry because you falsely detect things that aren't a fraud. Let's say you use what [Jan Hančič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185527/jan-hancic) suggested in the comments, to strip all non digit characters (which is not a bad approach):

```
I'm 21 years old. In 2012 I already had like 45k reputation on Stackoverflow.
```

This will result in 21201245 and could be part of a phone number.

I would suggest to filter new and updated profiles that look suspicious and to validate them manually. If it's not a valid entry because it contains a disguisedly e-mail or phone number, block it and send an e-mail to the user with the message to update his profile.

I would check the string like:

- does it contain: `@`, `at` or `[at]`, `dot`, `.com` (or any other often used TLD by your users)
- strip all non digit characters and check resulting numbers
- search for names of huge email companies, like Google, GMX, Yahoo, Apple (ME, iCloud) etc.

Here are some more questions and answers on how to find e-mails and phone numbers sing PHP:

- [How to detect telephone numbers in a text (and replace them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3764814/1456376)
- [Ultimate way to find phone numbers in PHP string with preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10141295/1456376)
- [How to get email address from a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028553/1456376)
- [Find and replace emails and phone numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11469957/1456376)

Comment: Thanks @insertusernamehere, For understanding my problem correctly and giving useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\d([,-. ] *\d){5}
```

It allows `, . -` and the space character. If you want to include more separator characters, just add them inside the `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$number    = '12.3555';

if(preg_match('/[\/0-9,-\.\s\\\]{6,}/',$number) && count(array_filter(str_split($number),'is_numeric')) >= 6){
  echo "phone number exists";
}
```

Comment: Dear prasanth, front slash, back slash and space not working.